# Property stored on 'window' object is removed on changing the 'Window.location.href'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm defining a property ( say, *myVar* ) on *window* object (to use it as a global variable ), but the problem is when I take the user on some different page by making use of `window.location.href` that global variable is lost, and becomes `undefined`.

Why is this unexpected behaviour of window obj variable is showing up, is it related to scope, and how to correct it ?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. HTTP is completely stateless. As a result anything you do on one page is lost as soon as a new page is loaded (even if you re-load the same page). You will need to store the information somewhere (localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies, server-side via AJAX) and then retrieve it again the next time the page is loaded.

Comment: This is not unexpected it is a new page.  Think of it as if you were driving a car with your bag of goods in the back, you stop, get a new car the bag remains in the old car unless you either store the bag somewhere or take it with you to the new car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object is built on page load. After the page loads, you add the property and that stays with the object.

When you redirect the user to another page, this is (obviously) interpreted as a new page, which means a new page load. By then, the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object is completely new.

If you have to keep this variable between page refreshes, that a look at:

## [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

### Syntax

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

## [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

### Syntax

```
// The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using Storage.setItem().
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

// The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');

// The syntax for removing the localStorage item is as follows:
localStorage.removeItem('myCat');

//The syntax for removing all the localStorage items is as follows:
// Clear all items
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: I'm familiar with these client-side storage , but whats the point of gloabal variable then.

Comment: To be available to scripts at all levels of scope within a single page - that being said globals are generally considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @MukulKumarJha Global variables persist on the current document lifecycle, you trigger a new lifecycle on a redirect (`window.location.href`).

Comment: great! @RoryMcCrossan @ silentw that exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the localStorage to store data that will persist between the pages of your website.

```
localStorage.setItem('myVar', value);

localStorage.getItem('myVar'); // gives value
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage